# Send Active MQ messages throught Camel that were sent to a AMQ topic while Camel was down

Tags: jms, apache-camel, activemq-classic

I have configured an Active MQ server that puts messages to a determined topic, in that moment a configured Camel server take this message and send it by a route to another server, the issue happens when Camel server is down and the Active MQ still continues putting messages in the topic and when Camel starts these past messages are not read by Camel, is there any way to configure Camel to start and read past messages from this Active MQ Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its ActiveMQ / JMS questions. Take a look at durable topics

- http://activemq.apache.org/how-do-durable-queues-and-topics-work.html

Comment: So yes, As I've read there it was needed to send from the suscriber (Camel) a client Id to Active MQ make this topic durable, and in this way Camel will route all the past Active MQ messages. I did it with this link http://camel.apache.org/durable-subscriber.html . Thank you so much for your answer